# Parsing DateTime from an Int32Array binary conversion

Tags: javascript, binary, uint32

Currently attempting to parse a managable datetime from a binary 'file'. Since the file is being uploaded in a web app, I am using javascript.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
var slice = arrayBuffer.slice( 1, 9 );
var date = new Uint32Array( slice );
console.log(date);
```

Console reports 'date' as

```
Uint32Array(2) [3068092018, 30617747]
0:3068092018
1:30617747
buffer:(...)
byteLength:(...)
byteOffset:(...)
length:(...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag):(...)
__proto__:TypedArray
```

or

```
date[0] = 3068092018
date[1] = 30617747
```

Unfortunately I have very little experience manipulating binary / big ints, in fact I don't even understand what format this is being stored in. How do I convert this into a manageable DateTime stamp for insertion into SQLite3?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateString = moment.unix(30617747).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

console.log(dateString)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe in chrome try Right-click an object in Chrome's console and select Store as Global Variable from the context menu. It will return something like temp1 as the variable name. Chrome also has a copy() method, so copy(temp1) in the console should copy that object to your clipboard, update your question with object :)

Comment: Returns 'undefined.' I am reading binary and storing in an arraybuffer, then after parsing a 'slice' of that arraybuffer I am storing that value in a Uint32Array.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if slice is manipulating the integrity of date value :-/ I was hoping to see the full js object to try and understand date format